# Proxy WebSocket connection using Apache & Socket.io

Tags: apache, proxy, socket.io

I'm having issues proxying my WebSocket connection (Socket.io) through Apache (2.4.6). I'm attempting to use the setup described on the Socket.io issues https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1696 but I keep getting an error in my developer tools that the connection failed during the WebSocket handshake:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=KPd7VBy4Yi7mj-wAAABN' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value must contain 'Upgrade'
```

This is happening because the `Connection` header is getting set to `Close` instead of `Upgrade`.

I've confirmed that the `proxy_wstunnel_module` module is loaded and when I look at the trace logs I can see it responding to some requests, but yet I still get the above error. I'm definitely not an Apache expert so I'm thinking something is incorrect in my `httpd.conf` file (I've tried confirming all the lines using the Apache documentation.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName example.domain.com
        ServerAlias example.domain.com

        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "content-type,x-requested-with"

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/$ /otherApp/home [PT]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling      [NC]
        RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

        <Directory />
                Options All
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ProxyRequests off

        <Proxy *>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        <Location />
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        ProxyPass /socket.io            ws://localhost:3000/socket.io
        ProxyPassReverse /socket.io     ws://localhost:3000/socket.io

        ProxyPass /AnotherApp ajp://localhost:8009/location
        ProxyPass /AnotherApp2  ajp://somewhere.else:8009/location2

        DocumentRoot /opt/appThings
        <Directory /opt/appThings>
                Options +Indexes
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone see anything obvious in my above `httpd.conf` file that would be causing this issue?

Let me know if there's other relevant information needed. I've looked through the logs but I'm not entirely sure what's relevant / what I need to be looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm not entirely sure the correct answer since another colleague of mine was the one who figured it out - and I'm not sure he understands the answer completely either.

I think what we found was there was a bug with the version of the `mod_rewrite` module we had. We had to compile the source of that module with the suggested patch and that got the proxying working correctly.

It also seems like there was some sort of "header stripping" going on for requests through the firewall. Seemed to be stripping off the `Connection: Upgrade` header which obviously caused our connection to fail.

So although I don't have as many specifics as I'd like, hopefully that might give someone else some clues as to what to look for in the future.

Comment: Ah, I'm currently working through the same sort of issue. I had tried using a later version of httpd (2.4.18 through Red Hat Software Collections on RHEL 7), but with no change in behaviour. It did work on my Mac (httpd 2.4.25).  I did note though, that even with 2.4.6, if you know that a URL will always be a WebSocket URL (ie. you don't cater to fallback), then you can use use ProxyPass /socket.io ws:127.0.0.1/ws